# Weird character (�) in SQL Server View definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encoding, view

I have generated the Create statement for a SQL Server view.

Pretty standard, although there is a some replacing happening on a varchar column, such as:

```
select Replace(txt, '�', '-')
```

What the heck is '`�`'?

When I run that against a row that contains that character, I am seeing the literal '`?`' being replaced.

Any ideas? Do I need some special encoding in my editor?

**Edit**
If it helps the end point is a Google feed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the script in the same encoding as that in which it was written. Even then, if your editor's font doesn't include a glyph for the character, it may still not display correctly.

When the script was created, did you choose an encoding, or accept the default? If the later, you need to find out which encoding was used. UTF-8 is likely.

However, in this case, the character may not be a mis-representation. [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) explains that this character is used as a replacement for some other character that cannot be represented. It's possible in your case that the code you are looking at is simply saying, if we have some data that could not be represented, treat it as a hyphen instead. In other words, this may be nothing to do with the script generation/viewing process, but rather a deliberate piece of code.

Comment: Using Sql MS, I've generated the script to clipboard and copied into a UTF-8 encoded new Notepad++ document. It's now a '[]' (square box), but if i copy and paste that it reverts to �. If it helps the end point is a Google feed.